# PHP: Convert negative timestamp to date

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a negative timestamp and I wanted to convert it to a readable date format.

```
$timestamp = -1861945262080;
```

If I use `date("d-m-Y", $timestamp)`, it will just output 12-08-2035.

Comment: How about using absolute value of timestamp?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking for. 12-08-2035 is a readable date format is it not?

Comment: That's a date around year -57033 and you'll need a 64-bit Unix version of PHP. Are you 100% sure it's a Unix timestamp?

Comment: Not sure what u asking for, want to change negative value to positive?

Comment: Apparently, in year 57,033 BC [Europe didn't have human population yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spreading_homo_sapiens.svg).

Comment: It's not readable @Jite becasue it's not clear -- is that the 12th of August in the US or the 8th of December in Europe?

Comment: d-m-Y, Day-Month-Year. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below piece of code transforms your UNIX timestamp to a valid date-month-year. However , **`passing pretty large negative unix timestamps can produce unexpected results`** as shown below.

```
 <?php
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimestamp(-1861945262080); //<--- Pass a UNIX TimeStamp
    echo $dt->format('d-m-Y');
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
12-08-2035
```

However, you still can pass negative timestamps to the above thing. Consider this excerpt from [`wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

> The Unix time number is zero at the Unix epoch, and increases by
>   exactly 86400 per day since the epoch. Thus 2004-09-16T00:00:00Z,
>   12677 days after the epoch, is represented by the Unix time number
>   12677 × 86400 = 1095292800. This can be extended backwards from the
>   epoch too, using negative numbers; thus 1957-10-04T00:00:00Z, 4472
>   days before the epoch, is represented by the Unix time number -4472 ×
>   86400 = -386380800.

So let's pass the `-386380800` to the above code.

```
 <?php
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimestamp(-386380800); //<--- Pass a UNIX TimeStamp
    echo $dt->format('d-m-Y');
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
04-10-1957
```

which is the expected output as per the sources.